# How to consume messages of the default dead letter queue in Spring Cloud Stream?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I configured the default DLQ as following:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      rabbit:
        default:
          consumer:
            auto-bind-dlq: true
            republish-to-dlq: true
            dead-letter-queue-name: my-dlq
```

I want to consume the messages in that default DLQ and process it in the business domain.

How can I listen those messages using **Spring Cloud Stream**?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built in, but [the documentation shows some techniques](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/2.2.1.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#rabbit-dlq-processing)...

> Because you cannot anticipate how users would want to dispose of dead-lettered messages, the framework does not provide any standard mechanism to handle them. If the reason for the dead-lettering is transient, you may wish to route the messages back to the original queue. However, if the problem is a permanent issue, that could cause an infinite loop. The following Spring Boot application shows an example of how to route those messages back to the original queue but moves them to a third “parking lot” queue after three attempts. The second example uses the RabbitMQ Delayed Message Exchange to introduce a delay to the re-queued message. In this example, the delay increases for each attempt. These examples use a @RabbitListener to receive messages from the DLQ. You could also use RabbitTemplate.receive() in a batch process.
>
> ...

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for a way to listen them using a `StreamListener`. As far as I understand, I have to use a `RabbitListener`.

Comment: You can use a `StreamListener` but you need to custom configure the binding, as described [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/2.2.1.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#_using_existing_queuesexchanges).